# Plugin that extends Woocommerce, errors

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a plugin that builds on Woocommerce. From the plugin, I want to sent an email using this guide:

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/

However, when I try to send the mail, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'WC_Email' not found`

Why is the Woocommerce class not found? I also tried using the hook plugins_loaded, but even then I get the Class not found error.

Thanks.

Comment: have you Add a Custom WooCommerce Email ? @Eelco Luurtsema

Comment: Yes I added a custom email class